# Upgrade AngularJS factory (ES5) to be used in Angular2 (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, upgrade, angular

I am trying to create an application using `Angular2` and `TypeScript` with `SystemJS` as module loader.
I allready have a working `AngularJS 1.X`with a corresponding framework, written in `JavaScript` (ES5) and using some basic functions of `Google Closure`.
Now i would like to use some functionality of that framework inside my `Angular2` app.
I have been reading a few tutorials about the `Angular2` `UpgradeAdapter`, including [this one](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html), where they say:

> It doesn’t really make sense to upgrade existing code to ES2015 or TypeScript.
>   If we have to upgrade to Angular 2, it probably makes more sense to just rewrite component by component.

To me this sounds like it is possible to use `AngularJS (ES5)` components/services in `Angular2 (TypeScript)` and vice versa.
However i am having problems when trying to upgrade a `AngularJS` `factory` to be used in my `Angular2` `Component`.

The situation:

I have a file `webclient.js`.
It provides a namespace `my.webclient` (using `goog.provide`).
Inside a `goog.scope`-function it then defines a `angular.module` called `my.webclient`.
Then a `factory` named `getWebclient` is created using `module.factory`.
This `factory` returns a `function`, which returns a `Promise`.
Now i would like to use this `factory` (`getWebclient`) inside my `Angular2` `Component`.

My `Angular2` `Component` looks like this:

```
import {Component, Inject} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import adapter from "./upgrade";    // adapter is a new UpgradeAdapter()

adapter.upgradeNg1Provider("getWebclient");

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "path-to-tamplate/app.html"
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(@Inject("getWebclient") getWebclient) {
        getWebclient().then(webclient => {
            // If the Promise succeed i'll can log the webclients name property.
            console.log(webclient.name);
        })
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

However this results in a `DI Exception` with the message

> No provider for getWebclient! (AppComponent -> getWebclient).

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I changed the `bootstrap` line to

```
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["my.webclient"], {strictDi: true});
```

and now there aren't any errors. However, now the `AppComponent` does not seem to be loaded into the DOM, using the `<my-app/>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, there are some useful details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

For one thing: you should no longer use `<my-app/>` tag.